# I want to use Android studio webview to open an .html file from local host, but the name of the file will be a variable

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, localhost, android-webview

I want to store several different .html files in the assets folder of my Android project.
I then want to use webview to open one of these files.
The actual name of the file I want to open is not fixed, instead it will be returned by another piece of code.
Can anyone advise me how I can use a variable name in a webview url path to a local host?
For example: myWebView.loadUrl("file://android_assets/***q***.htm") where ***q*** will vary and will be completed by a different existing piece of code.

To recover the name of the file (***q***) I am using the working code below:

```
val q: String = text_view.getText().toString()
        val keyword = q + "image"
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH)
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, keyword)
        startActivity(intent)
```

To run the webview activity,  I use an android button and I am using the webview code below, but I can't see how to make part of the url path variable. Can anyone advise?

```
webview.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
myWebView.loadUrl("file://android_assets/q.htm")
```

Comment: if I not get it wrong you can use `myWebView.loadUrl("file://android_assets/" + yourVariablel + ".htm")`

Comment: I have tried Usama Altaf's suggestion and it works fine as far as the code goes. It does allow me to ask for a variable url so thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way see loadItFromanywhereInCaseFromAsset and loadUrlPath can do concatination of path may help you

```
public class HtmlPageLoadActivity extends Activity{

    private WebView webView = null;
    private String prefix = "file://android_assets/";

    private class WebViewOverrideUrl extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            proceedUrl(view, Uri.parse(url));
            return true;
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            proceedUrl(view, request.getUrl());
            return true;
        }

        private void proceedUrl(WebView view, Uri uri) {
            try {
                view.loadUrl(uri.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewOverrideUrl());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);        
    }

   //you can call this method from different existing piece of code where you get file name, prefix allready given above or you can update this code
   public void loadItFromanywhereInCaseFromAsset(String filenameWithExtension){
       
     loadUrlPath(prefix+filenameWithExtension)   
 
   }


   public void loadUrlPath(String path){    
     
     webView.loadUrl(path);
   }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            if (newProgress >= 100) {

            }
            setValue(newProgress);
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        }
    }

    public void setValue(int progress) {

    }
}
```